# FakeAsync/tick (Async/whenStable) vs detectChanges()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous

Could you please help me differentiate those two things.

According to my understanding, if you only work with observable, you can use detectChanges(). So you can change a component property directly or spy on a service call and return an observable, then you call detectChanges(), the changes will be available on html elements.

But for [(ngModel)] on input fields you need to call tick() for the changes to be render on html element.

So I'd it would be great if I know what they do and when to use what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### detectChanges

The method `detectChanges` is available on the [ViewRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewRef).

```
class ViewRef extends ChangeDetectorRef {
  // inherited from core/ChangeDetectorRef
  markForCheck(): void   <-----------------------------
  detach(): void
  detectChanges(): void
  checkNoChanges(): void
  reattach(): void
}
```

`ViewRef` is an underlying representation of a component. When writing tests instead of `ViewRef` another abstraction is introduced which is `fixture`:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
```

It wraps the component similar to `ViewRef`.

`detectChanges` method runs change detection for the underlying component and performs the following operations:

- update input bindings properties
- update DOM

and many others.

To learn more you can read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f). So in order to validate changes in the DOM or validate input bindings you need to run `detectChanges`.

#### tick

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function) describe it pretty well:

> The tick function is one of the Angular testing utilities and a
>   companion to fakeAsync. You can only call it within a fakeAsync body.
>
> Calling tick() simulates the passage of time until all pending
>   asynchronous activities finish, including the resolution of the
>   getQuote promise in this test case.

With `ngModel` you need to call it because the control that is created inside `ngModel` is registered asynchonously. Here is the quote from [the article by Victor Savkin on forms](https://blog.nrwl.io/angular-forms-in-depth-ecb7c58166b5#23b6):

> To make it work, NgModel doesn’t add a form control synchronously — it
>   does it in a microtask. In the example above, the three ngModels will
>   schedule three microtasks to add the speaker, title, and highRating
>   controls.