# Does fixture.whenStable() actually do anything in my angular tests if not within an async test execution zone?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have been reading a lot about angular testing lately and the pairs are always async+fixture.whenStable and fakeAsync+tick, however you can always call fixtrue.whenStable as it is not tightly coupled. If you call it when not using the async utility to track promises in a test zone will it actually do anything?

For example:

```
it('should be able to do this thing that needs some async setup', () => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable().then()
});
```

I understand the difference between `FakeAsync/Tick` and `fixture.detectChanges`. My question is regarding what `fixture.whenstable` will do when inside of a `FakeAsync` execution zone as an `Async` zone should keep track of async work allowing `fixture.whenstable` to hook into that tracking, at least as I understand it. Or indeed if used and not within an async execution zone at all.

So if fixture.whenstable is used inside a FakeAsync function, or a function that does not setup an async execution zone, will it work as intended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FakeAsync/tick (Async/whenStable) vs detectChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342594/fakeasync-tick-async-whenstable-vs-detectchanges)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No the `whenStable()` does nothing if you test without `async` or `fakeAsync`. What `whenStable()` does is to wait for all tasks in the test `NgZone` to complete. When you don't test with async the `NgZone` does not get created at all and `whenStable()` just returns immediately.

If you want more detail check the code for ComponentFixture in [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts).

Comment: Does fakeAsync setup a zone that whenstable() can use?

Comment: Yes both `fakeAsync()` and `async()` create a zone.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer may have been correct when it was written, but as of late 2020, when using `node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js`, I don't think it is anymore.  I can't find a citation in the docs, but I can confirm experimentally that a test zone is *always* used, and that `whenStable` waits for its tasks to complete.

This is very simple to try for yourself.  Just create an empty test, and add

```js
//// In my.component.ts
import { timer } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  template: `<p>{{clock|async}}</p>`,
  // ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  /** @internal */ public readonly clock = timer(0,1000).pipe(map(() => new Date()));
}


//// In `my.component.spec.ts`
beforeEach(async () => {
    testBed.configureTestingModule(...);
    await testBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = testBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    await fixture.whenStable();
});
```

Because rxjs `timer` uses `setInterval` under the hood, it's flagged as always having a pending task, so `whenStable` never resolves.  Jasmine will fail with a timeout, waiting for the Promise returned by the setup method to resolve.  (Ask me how I discovered this...)

Comment: This may be because the CLI already includes zone.js/testing even if fakeAsync and waitForAsync aren't used. Without them, whenStable will check the task queue but the test function won't, so there may be tasks left if whenStable isn't called last.

Comment: It looks like I wasnt clear in my question as what I was referring to async the method, not the keyword.

Comment: I understand that. My example happens to use an `async` setup function, but my point was to illustrate that even though the function is not wrapped in a call to `fakeAsync`, it still runs inside the test (FakeAsync) Zone.

Comment: @Coderer how did you discover this?

Comment: My last comment there is a bit jokey, I had a service that uses a `timer`, and a component which uses observables exposed by the service, which are derived from the timer.  This basically made it impossible to write tests using `whenStable`, which is used under the hood by some Angular Material test utils.  I had open issues with them about it, not sure if it ever got resolved -- I moved to another project...

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap your test code into [waitForAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync)

this is new recommended way to test async code in angular

```js
  @Component()
  export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    async ngOnInit() {
      // to test component with async ngOnInit use waitForAsync
    }
  }

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  );
```

Comment: Actually, https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-waitforasync shows a test using both `waitForAsync()` and `whenStable()`. So I don't think `waitForAsync()` is meant to replace `whenStable()`.