# Using Angular fixture.whenStable synchronously

Tags: angular

I have a *synchronous* test of the form:

```
it('should do things' () => {
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

  button = compiled.querySelector('#buttonid');
  button.click();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(state).toBe(whatIwant);
  }

  button.click();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(state).toBe(whatIwant);
  }

});
```

It works, but I don't understand why.

Everything I read online indicates that `whenStable` should only be used in an `async` test, but the above test does not wrap the testing function with the async() wrapper. If I do that, the test fails (that is, the expects fail because those changes to not appear to be reflected in the component yet).

According to another answer here, using the `whenStable` method in a synchronous test is pointless:
[Does fixture.whenStable() actually do anything in my angular tests if not within an async test execution zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479998/does-fixture-whenstable-actually-do-anything-in-my-angular-tests-if-not-within)

> No the whenStable() does nothing if you test without async of
>   fakeAsync. What whenStable() does is to wait for all tasks in the test
>   NgZone to complete. When you don't test with async the NgZone does not
>   get created at all and whenStable() just returns immediately.

However, if I take their word for it, and I omit the `whenStable` wrapper, and just make the assertions after calling fixture.detectChanges(), the test fails.

So, to summarize:

- When I use `async` and `whenStable` together, the test fails.
- When I use no `async` or `whenStable`, the test fails.
- When I use no `async` and `whenStable`, the test *passes*: by the time I make each check on the state of the component, the state has been updated to what I expect.

**This test only passes when I use `whenStable`. What I'd like to know is: why?**

So, it seems as though, in contradiction to the accepted answer on the above question, whenStable is doing something here. What is that thing, exactly? Does the context I've omitted here (what happens upon clicking a button, etc.) matter?

According to the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/testing

> The fixture.whenStable() returns a promise that resolves when the JavaScript engine's task queue becomes empty.

I'm unsure what this means exactly: can anybody clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This test only passes when I use `whenStable`. What I'd like to know is:
>   why?

Well, that is most probably because the tests execute and finish before the *async* operations inside the `whenStable` execute (and fail), so you end up with a test with no expectations (and thus no possibility to fail).